# How Can I build an app to call the Power BI Refresh History?

Tags: visual-studio, api, powerbi

I am trying to create a simple VS App that will check the refresh history of a Power BI Dataset in a workspace in an organization. Although Microsoft has a ton of stuff on their website and Github, it seems like it always gets me 90% there then I'm a sitting duck and can't get it to work. I'm using the service principle approach to log in and check the refresh history. If the refresh history is after a given threshold, send an email. Most of my monitors are in VS and then I create an exe that I run through a scheduler. Wanted to do the same thing here.

Comment: Also important to know is that I need to authenticate using the secret key (logging in as a service principal account). It seems like the authentication is the biggest problem. I was able to get the basic powershell scripts to work and return data, but when trying in C#, I get a 403 response. Too difficult to tell if it's a problem with the auth token or with the permissions on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

I do this via the Power BI REST APIs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getrefreshhistoryingroup). Specifically, I use a custom connector in a logic app (instructions for that here: https://youtu.be/2Cgi3s7Zs5M). The same thing could be done in Power Automate. The nice thing is that you can take an action based on the value returned, all running in the cloud (including the email part).